# Failed to execute Default terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

Whenever I use a voodo-kali program, and I launch it, I always get

```
Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator. Input/output error`
```

and then a "do not show again" dialog box.

I have looked on other sites, but couldn't find a solution.

Edit: If this helps, other terminal emulators work, just not the default one.

Comment: Voodo-kali program is a program that runs kali on a windows machine using the remote desktop connection. The exact error message I get is "Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator. Input/output error" and then a do not show again dialog box. There is no other information

Comment: What programs are you launching? How are you launching them? If a non-default terminal emulator works, does it stop working when you set it to default? Please include more details in the specifics of your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the only possible solution to this issue:

Log out from your account, root/yourNameAccount, Now on the login screen, you need to hit this key combinations= CTRL+ALT+F1. After that, enter your login credentials like you would normally do on a login screen. In the next steps, enter these commands:

```
1. sudo apt update && apt install xfce4-terminal -y
2. sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

> Note: You do not need to use `sudo` if you are logged in as root already. You can use these commands without typing `sudo`.

The second command here is for updating the terminal preferences, in other words, you are telling your system to use the specific terminal as the default terminal. The terminal you installed in the first step will be listed there as `xfce4`, you then need to enter the number of your `xfce4` terminal and press the `Enter` key. Done. Now you need to type `reboot` and hit ENTER. After your system restarts, you can log in to your Kali system and check whether your terminal is working now or not, if your terminal is not opening by clicking on the icon located on the top status bar then you can also try this key combination: CTRL+ALT+T.

To get more help in understanding the above process I've explained in case you are a newbie to Kali, you can also watch this [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXuyk5STx7TcOYfW9eFMBkExEbISeswB/view?usp=sharing)